# Why am I getting a list out of range error while trying to save an excel workbook in python?

Tags: python, excel, list, save, openpyxl

I'm trying to create a workbook,Edit it and save it.
Here is how the code looks :

```
cur_wb=openpyxl.Workbook()

-- Code modifying the values of cells. 
Example : target_cell._style = copy(template_cell._style) --

filename="DB-"+months[inm]+".xlsx"
cur_wb.save(filename="output/"+filename)
```

```
File "Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 407, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 293, in save_workbook
    writer.save()
  File "Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 275, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 84, in write_data
    stylesheet = write_stylesheet(self.workbook)
File "Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 253, in write_stylesheet
    xf.alignment = wb._alignments[style.alignmentId]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why am I getting this error? Is it because I used copy?

Comment: Yes, definitely appears it is an issue due to the copying part of your code messing with the style. The line numbering in the traceback suggests you're not using the latest release of Openpyxl. If so you should update the version and try again. If there are still issues you'll need to expand on the copying process.

Answer (score 0):

So,
I just changed that one copy line of code.
I created a temporary NamedStyle, Copied the styles(Font,Alignment,Fill,Border) of the template cell to the NamedStyle and applied the Namedstyle to the target cell.
This fixed the issue.